# I have a problem with the message.content in python for a discord bot

Tags: python

When I make a loop the `message.content` never refreshes.

I tried a lot of things but I don't really know how to code in Python.

```
import discord
import time
i = 0

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'start':
            while True:
                print(str(message.content))

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

I want to see the `message.content` refresh when I retype a message in Discord. Can somebody helps me please?

Comment: Every time you send a new message, `on_message` is triggered again so a loop is not needed, unless I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Your bot can't see any of the changes as you type. you have to send the message to discord (Read: press `enter`) before discord can send it to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made a bot as a class, but I've always used `@` operators before defining functions. My bot looks more like this:

```
@bot.event # I think this is important
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="with your mom"))
    print(bot.user.name + ' is now up and running')

@bot.command(pass_context=True, description='stuff') # again I think this is important
async def process_command(ctx): # pass context of message into bot
    print(dir(ctx)) # show what methods are available (or just look up documentation)
    print(ctx)
```